# How to build a regex in Hive to get string until Nth occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I have some sample data in Hive as

```
select "abc:def:ghi:jkl" as data
union all
select "jkl:mno:23ar:stu:abc:def:ghi:7345" as data
```

I want to extract the strings until 3rd colon so that I get the output as

```
abc:def:ghi
jkl:mno:23ar
```

I want to keep N as variable so that I can shrink the output text as needed. How do I do this in Hive?

Comment: You can use something like that select split(str,':')[3] from table

Comment: i think this will give the 4th element of the array and not the entire string that i care for

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(`data`, '^([^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+).*$', "$1")
FROM
  ( SELECT "abc:def:ghi:jkl" AS `data`
   UNION ALL SELECT "jkl:mno:23ar:stu:abc:def:ghi:7345" AS `data`) AS tmp
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a little explanation with your code?

Comment: sure, the regular expression use capture group to filter the first N(3) colon delimetered, other text than that are dropped out

Comment: I meant could you update your code-only answer to provide some explanation for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

With variable:

```
set hivevar:n=3; --variable, you can pass it to the script

with your_table as(
select stack(2,"abc:def:ghi:jkl", "jkl:mno:23ar:stu:abc:def:ghi:7345")as data
)

select regexp_replace(regexp_extract(data,'([^:]*:){1,${hivevar:n}}',0),':$','') from your_table;
```

Result:

```
OK
abc:def:ghi
jkl:mno:23ar
Time taken: 0.105 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Quantifier `{1,${hivevar:n}}` after variable substitution will become `{1,3}` which means 1 to 3 times, this allows to extract values shorter than 3. If you need not to extract shorter values, use `{${hivevar:n}}` quantifier. If there are < than N elements, it will extract empty string in this case.

Answer (score 0):

With using split and posexplode functions, you can combine again with filtering position

```
select t.dataId, concat_ws(":", collect_list(t.cell)) as firstN from (
SELECT x.dataId, pos as pos, cell
   FROM  (
     select 1 as dataId, "jkl:mno:23ar:stu:abc:def:ghi:7345" as data
      union all
     select 2 as dataId, "abc:def:ghi:7345" as data
   ) x 
   LATERAL VIEW posexplode(split(x.data,':')) dataTable AS pos, cell
) t
where t.pos<3
group by t.dataId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select substring_index('abc:def:ghi:jkl',':',3) as data
Union all
Select substring_index('jkl:mno:23ar:stu:abc:def:ghi:7345',':',3) as data;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code might be the solution to the question, it's a good practice to include an explanation of what it does and how it solves the problem, so that future visitors can learn from it.